# CNN model input, output size type-error message

Tags: model, conv-neural-network, typeerror

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class FashionClassifier(nn.Module): 
    def init(self, num_classes): 
        super(FashionClassifier, self).init()
        self.conv_layers = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(),nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2), 
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(), nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2), 
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1), nn.ReLU(), nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )


        self.conv_output_size = self._get_conv_output_size()

        self.fc_layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=self.conv_output_size, out_features=3),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),  # Add dropout for regularization
            nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=num_classes)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_layers(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc_layers(x)
        return x

    def _get_conv_output_size(self):
        test_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
        with torch.no_grad():
            test_output = self.conv_layers(test_input)
        return test_output.view(test_output.size(0), -1).size(1)
```

An error occurs when executing the next code.

error message:
`TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (dict, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!dict!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)
- (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
  didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (!dict!, !Parameter!, !Parameter!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, !tuple of (int, int)!, int)

`

how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the code you are executing? (the line that create/use the model). When changing `init` to `__init__` I can create your model without issue and no error, and I can create a dummy input and feed it in the model